# Webform Drupal 8, node and form, how to pass node field info to form?

Tags: 8, webforms

I don't understand how node integration with webform works.  How do I pass data from a node with a webform field to an instance of that form?  I created a form with email and location.  Then I created a content type with location, description, date, and a webform field and then I added some content to it. How do I associate the location from the content type to an instance of a form?  How does the "Default submission data (YAML)" work?  I put "[current-page:title]" in there expecting it to populate the form, but I don't understand how to specify what form field it goes to or if I'm using the right syntax or what??

Answer (score 1):

The location node is considered the 'source entity' and is automatically tracked.

You can use the [webform_submission:node] to pull information from the location node into the 'Default webform submission data (YAML)'. For example, to get the location's title you should use the [webform_submission:node:title] token.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working.  This is an impressive module on many levels.